# TKinter Grid Positionning

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make the following with Canvas. But the bottom canvas stays centered and does not spread on all column and on one row. Where is the issue ?

Bonus: where to specify the width and height for the root windows (for instance height 400 and width 300) and grid will calculate accordingly each row and column size?

Thank you

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

can_l = Canvas(root, bg='green')
can_c = Canvas(root, bg='blue')
can_r = Canvas(root, bg='red')
can_b = Canvas(root, bg='cyan')

can_l.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=3)
can_c.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=3)
can_r.grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=3)
can_b.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3, rowspan=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `sticky` attribute? Widgets are centered unless you specifically request that they stretch to fill the space allocated.

Comment: ok it works, but why is columnspan =3 not understood as a spread of my bottom canvas ?

Comment: It _is_ understood as "a spread of my bottom canvas". `grid` allocates all three columns to the bottom canvas. However, the canvas is smaller than the allocated space. If you want the canvas to fill the allocated space, you need to tell `grid` to fill the space. Otherwise the default is to center the widget in the allocated space. That's how `grid` is designed to work.

Comment: *"where to specify the width and height for the root window"* Use `geometry()`: `root.geometry('400x300')`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bryan, I was thinking that sticky was only to position a widget like a button in a wider widget like a canvas

I dont understand though why it does not respect me when I say columnspan = 3 for the bottom canvas

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
    
can_l = Canvas(root, bg='green')
can_c = Canvas(root, bg='blue')
can_r = Canvas(root, bg='red')
can_b = Canvas(root, bg='cyan')

can_l.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=3)
can_c.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=3)
can_r.grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=1, rowspan=3)
can_b.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3, rowspan=1, sticky ='swse')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I dont understand though why it does not respect me when I say columnspan = 3 for the bottom canvas"_ - it _does_ respect you. All three columns are allocated to the bottom canvas. The bottom canvas is too small to fit the allocated space so it is centered. That is how `grid` is designed to work.

Comment: `sticky='swse'` should be `sticky='nwse'` instead.